# Display array values in table format in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.1, html-table

I have an array like so:

```
array:55 [▼
  0 => array:13 [▼
    "product_id" => "1"
    "name" => "Glowing Antique Multi-Color Necklace And Hangings"
    "product_code" => "DIV-COL-0001-0001"
    "option_code" => ""
    "net_price" => "693.00"
    "sellerCommission" => "450.00"
    "moderatorCommission" => "14.00"
    "principalModeratorCommission" => "17.00"
    "affiliateCommission" => "28.00"
    "accountType" => "affiliate"
  ]
  25 => array:13 [▼
    "product_id" => "24"
    "name" => "Blue Colored Cotton Zip Pouch (3 Nos.)"
    "product_code" => "PRA-KEN-0002-0006"
    "option_code" => ""
    "net_price" => "184.62"
    "sellerCommission" => "120.00"
    "moderatorCommission" => "4.00"
    "principalModeratorCommission" => "5.00"
    "affiliateCommission" => "7.00"
    "accountType" => "affiliate"
  ]
  26 => array:13 [▼
    "product_id" => "25"
    "name" => "Side Hanging Purse (2 Nos.)"
    "product_code" => "PRA-KEN-0002-0007"
    "option_code" => ""
    "net_price" => "184.62"
    "sellerCommission" => "120.00"
    "moderatorCommission" => "4.00"
    "principalModeratorCommission" => "5.00"
    "affiliateCommission" => "7.00"
    "accountType" => "affiliate"
 ]
  44 => array:13 [▼
    "product_id" => "24"
    "name" => "Blue Colored Cotton Zip Pouch (3 Nos.)"
    "product_code" => "PRA-KEN-0002-0006"
    "option_code" => ""
    "net_price" => "184.62"
    "sellerCommission" => "120.00"
    "moderatorCommission" => "4.00"
    "principalModeratorCommission" => "5.00"
    "affiliateCommission" => "7.00"
    "accountType" => "principal_moderator"
  ]

  // And the list continues ...

]
```

The code that I have tried so far, works correctly to a certain extent.

```
<tr>
    <th style="vertical-align: top;">Id</th>
    <th style="vertical-align: top;">Details</th>
    <th style="vertical-align: top;">Net Price</th>
    <th style="vertical-align: top;">Invoicer<br /> Commission</th>
    <th style="vertical-align: top;">Moderator Commission</th>
    <th style="vertical-align: top;">Principal Moderator Commission</th>
    <th style="vertical-align: top;">Affiliate Commission</th>
</tr>

@foreach($products as $product)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $product['product_id'] }}</td>
        <td>
            <img src="{{ $product['image'] }}" alt="{{ $product['name'] }}" class="pull-left" style="margin-right: 15px">
            <a href="{{ $product['page_url'] }}" class="links-dark">{{ $product['name'] }}</a><br />
            Product Code: {{ $product['product_code'] }}<br />
            @if($product['option_code'] !== '')
                Option Code: {{ $product['option_code'] }}
            @endif
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ $product['net_price'] }}</td>

        @if($product['accountType'] === 'seller')
            <td class="text-right">{{ number_format($product['sellerCommission'], 2) }}</td>
        @else
            <td class="text-right">--</td>
        @endif

        @if($product['accountType'] === 'moderator')
            <td class="text-right">{{ number_format($product['moderatorCommission'], 2) }}</td>
        @else
            <td class="text-right">--</td>
        @endif

        @if($product['accountType'] === 'principal_moderator')
            <td class="text-right">{{ number_format($product['principalModeratorCommission'], 2) }}</td>
        @else
            <td class="text-right">--</td>
        @endif

        @if($product['accountType'] === 'affiliate')
            <td class="text-right">{{ number_format($product['affiliateCommission'], 2) }}</td>
        @else
            <td class="text-right">--</td>
        @endif
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

The above code works, but it adds a new row to the table which is what I am not looking for. I do not want to add a new row, instead I would like to display the required data in that row only.

Meaning, for the `product_id = 24`, (*except for the option code*), there are 2 `accountType` attached viz., `affiliate` and `principal_moderator`. I would like to populate a single row with that data instead of 2 different rows.

How do I achieve it ??

I know this must be far easy, but I have failed to solve it, because I am still at the learning stage.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

**P.S.:** All the values are coming from the database, and the number of child arrays can be infinite.

Comment: firstly, I advice you paginate this query for performance reasons

Comment: I have already done that using a plugin from https://datatables.net/

Comment: I think the issue is with your `$product['accountType']` in if-else statement. Please revisit.

Comment: What is it, can you guide me the correct way then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group rows and make accountType property an array. Basically create new array, loop through products and add them into new array if they are not already added and if they are then add accountType to it. Something like this:

```
$grouped = array();
foreach($products as $product) {
    if(!array_key_exists($product['product_id'], $grouped)) {
        $grouped[$product['product_id']] = $product;
        $grouped[$product['product_id']]['accountTypes'] = array($product['accountType']);
    }else {
        $grouped[$product['product_id']]['accountTypes'][] = $product['accountType'];
    }
}
```

Then you use grouped data to display data and on accountType check you check if that type exists in accountTypes property.

Comment: Your solution worked, but there is an issue.. In the array, there are certain products that have the same `product_id` but with different `option_code` (default will be blank), and I want them to be displayed as well.. How can I do that ?

Comment: On modifying already existing grouped product check if option_code is blank and if not then set it to grouped product.

`if($product['option_code'] != '') {
   $grouped[$product['product_id']]['option_code'] = $product['option_code'];
  }`

Should work correctly as long there is only one option_code per product.

Comment: There can be multiple `option_code` for 1 product.. For example, there can be a cloth - Product 1 - with different sizes [opt-1 => 'OPT-1-1', opt-1 => 'OPT-1-2', etc etc] having multiple option_code, here (OPT-1-1, OPT-1-2).. How do I go about it ?

Comment: Same way as with accountType- turn it into array and keep adding new ones.

Comment: Okay.. And then how do I check it ??

Comment: `$grouped[$product['product_id']]['option_codes'] = array();
  if($product['option_code'] != '') {
   $grouped[$product['product_id']]['option_codes'] = $product['option_code'];
  }`